# Ansible role needs to run in a middle of tasks files of another role - how to create a maintainable playbook?

Tags: apache-kafka, ansible

I am using Ansible to create role that runs Kafka on a host. Kafka is running as a Podman image, host is running RHEL 8. I've also created a role that can download a set of images from image registry (e.g. Kafka, Zookeeper) images.

The problem with Podman is that it requires the image to be pulled from image registry on behalf of a custom user running the image.

And there the hen and egg problem occurs.

1. I am installing Kafka with Ansible role that creates user first.
2. To install Kafka I need images from 'image-registry' role.
3. To pull images, I need Kafka user from Kafka role.
4. I am in a loop.

When using order in playbook:

```
roles:
  - "image-registry-pull"
  - "install-kafka"
```

I cannot pull images before running 'install-kafka' because user doesn't exist yet.

When using order:

```
roles:
  - "install-kafka"
  - "image-registry-pull"
```

I cannot install and run Kafka because a part of this role is starting a pod that expects the image. At the point of time when attempting to run Kafka pod, I don't have image.

How can I split a playbook in order to:

1. Run a set of tasks files from Kafka role, install user in the meantime
2. Install Podman images (when user is already created)
3. Resume Kafka role - start pod with image being already downloaded.

I was thinking about a playbook:

```
tasks:
  - import_role:
      name: install-kafka
      tasks_from: kafka_user # To install user first
  - import_role:
      name: image-registry-pull # Pull images
  - import_role:
      name: install-kafka # Run role again (and attempt to create user again)
```

Do you think it's a good solution?

How to create a playbook that is easily maintainable?

Comment: 1) Create the user 2) do something like `docker login; docker pull;` 3) Run image... I see no loop there

Comment: If you dont need podman, then Confluent has [Ansible playbooks](https://docs.confluent.io/ansible/current/overview.html). Otherwise, wouldn't deploying k8s operators make more sense than using podman?